# Regex parsing data from between <> PCRE

Tags: regex, parsing, vpn

I need to parse some ASA logs and pull from 2 fields, the User and Address field:

> Jan 21 11:03:31 vpn1.domain.com %ASA-5-223065: Group
>    User  IP <255.255.255.255> AnyConnect
>   parent session started.
>
> Jan 21 11:03:32 vpn1.domain.com %ASA-3-844021: TunnelGroup
>    GroupPolicy  User  IP
>   <255.255.255.255> No IPv6 address available for SVC connection
>
> Jan 21 11:03:32 vpn1.domain.com %ASA-4-844044: Group
>    User  IP <255.255.255.255> First TCP SVC
>   connection established for SVC session.
>
> Jan 21 11:03:32 vpn1.domain.com %ASA-5-844025: Group
>    User  IP <255.255.255.255> TCP SVC
>   connection established without compression
>
> Jan 21 11:03:32 vpn1.domain.com %ASA-3-844049: Group
>    User  IP <255.255.255.255> Address
>   <255.255.255.255> assigned to session

I currently have this:

```
(User <([^>]*)>)|(Address <(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)>)
```

Which gives me:

```
User <pp5678> and Address <255.255.255.255> respectively
```

How can I modify it to give me just pp5678 and 255.255.255.255 without the field tags and "<>"?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? PCRE/Boost? Or any other?

Comment: You should probably use groups anyway, which all engines supports

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<=User <)[^>]*|(?<=Address <)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX2jP7/1)

I only put `User <` and `Address <` into *positive lookbehinds*. PCRE supports lookbehinds of known (fixed) width.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the wrong groups. Notice that you put the part between the `<>` in a separate group. So to get `pp5678` instead of `User <pp5678>` just use group 2 instead of 1. For the address I'd say »likewise«, but you deliberately used a non-capturing group there (starting with `?:`) which you'd have to remedy first.

Speaking of which, you probably don't need the outer groups anyway, since you're not grouping anything that needs grouping *and* you're not interested in the group's match. So just use

```
User <([^>]*)>|Address <((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)>
```

as regex and use groups 1 and 2 for your user name or address, respectively.

If you don't need the groups to distinguish user names and IP addresses and only need the match as is, you can also use the approach shown by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35034234/73070) in his answer.